# Convert panda dataframe group of values to multiple lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe, where I listed items, and categorised them:

```
col_name    |col_group
-------------------------
id          | Metadata
listing_url | Metadata
scrape_id   | Metadata
name        | Text
summary     | Text
space       | Text
```

To reproduce:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame([
    ['id','metadata'],
    ['listing_url','metadata'],
    ['scrape_id','metadata'],
    ['name','Text'],
    ['summary','Text'],
    ['space','Text']],
    columns=['col_name', 'col_group'])
```

Can you suggest how I can convert this dataframe to multiple lists based on "col_group":

```
Metadata = ['id','listing_url','scraping_id]
Text = ['name','summary','space']
```

This is to allow me to pass these lists of columns to panda and drop columns.

I googled a lot and got stuck: all answers are about converting lists to df, not vice versa. Should I aim to convert into dictionary, or list of lists?

I have over 100 rows, belonging to 10 categories, so would like to avoid manual hard-coding.

Comment: You'll get better answers with a [mcve] including actual sample input data and expected output

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_vars = df.groupby('col_group').agg(list)['col_name'].to_dict()
```

Output:

```
>>> my_vars
{'Text': ['name', 'summary', 'space'], 'metadata': ['id', 'listing_url', 'scrape_id']}
```

The recommended usage would be just `my_vars['Text']` to access the `Text`, and etc.  If you *must* have this as distinct names you can force it upon your target scope, e.g. `globals`:

```
globals().update(df.groupby('col_group').agg(list)['col_name'].to_dict())
```

Result:

```
>>> Text
['name', 'summary', 'space']
>>> metadata
['id', 'listing_url', 'scrape_id']
```

However I would advise against that as you might unwittingly overwrite some of your other objects, or they might not be in the proper scope you needed (e.g. `locals`).

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
In [245]: res = df.groupby('col_group', as_index=False)['Col_name'].apply(list)

In [248]: res.tolist()                                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[248]: [['id', 'listing_url', 'scrape_id'], ['name', 'summary', 'space']]
```

Comment: thanks! this is 99% what I am trying to get. Can these lists be built from their 'Col_group' name?  i.e.  Metadata  = ['id', 'listing_url', 'scrape_id'] , Text = ['name', 'summary', 'space']?

Comment: Like how exactly. Can you tell me what do you actually need?

Answer (score 2):

I've try this code:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame([
    [1, 'url_a', 'scrap_a', 'name_a', 'summary_a', 'space_a'],
    [2, 'url_b', 'scrap_b', 'name_b', 'summary_b', 'space_b'],
    [3, 'url_c', 'scrap_c', 'name_c', 'summary_c', 'space_ac']],
    columns=['id', 'listing_url', 'scrape_id', 'name', 'summary', 'space'])
print(df)

for row in df.iterrows():
    print(row[1].to_list())
```

which give this answer:

```
[1, 'url_a', 'scrap_a', 'name_a', 'summary_a', 'space_a']
[2, 'url_b', 'scrap_b', 'name_b', 'summary_b', 'space_b']
[3, 'url_c', 'scrap_c', 'name_c', 'summary_c', 'space_ac']
```

You can use

```
for row in df[['name', 'summary', 'space']].iterrows():
```

to only iter over specific columns.